# spacy identifies names with digit in it as PERSON entity

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy 2.3.2 version
while predicting names like santosh12647578 kadge16577. spacy identifies them as PERSON entity.
How do I tell spacy if it encounters number in it don't consider it as PERSON entity.

Can I use entity ruler for this. If can how I should I approach this
Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rule-based components after the NER statistical model to correct common errors.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

def reduce_person_entities(doc):
    new_ents = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == "PERSON" and any(char.isdigit() for tok in ent for char in tok.text):
            pass
        else:
            new_ents.append(ent)
    doc.ents = new_ents
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(reduce_person_entities, after='ner')

doc = nlp('Some example usernames include kadge16577 (Kadge Smith).')
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent, ent.label_)
```

Output

```
Kadge Smith PERSON
```

Comment: special characters like hyphen and ` are also non alphanumeric. with this code then name like santosh` kadge will not be identified as person entity  how to handle this then

Comment: @Santosh Kadge Then you can use `is_digit` as the condition